# AWS EC2 rettirement

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I got the mail from Amazon regarding my EC2 as follows:

EC2 has detected degradation of the underlying hardware hosting your Amazon EC2 instance (instance-ID: xxxxxxxx) associated with your AWS account (AWS Account ID: xxxxxx) in the ap-south-1 region. Due to this degradation your instance could already be unreachable. We will stop your instance after 2020-12-29 22:00:00 UTC. Please take appropriate action before this time.

The affected instances are listed below:

xxxxxxx

So what would I do now to keep my data safe ?

Comment: Create AMI of the instance. You can also snapshot your EBS volumes independently, if you want.

Comment: the snapshot or AMI will restore the hard disk to its last position ?

Comment: It will restore data up until the time when you took them. You can manually copy data out of the instance if you prefer to do it this way. Then you copy it back to new one. You have 2 weeks to migrate to new instance.

Comment: hmm that's fine but what about the hosting and name server I have configured in the old hard disk. Will it available same as before ?

Comment: I don't know what and how did you setup your instance. Your question does not provide any details. You have two weeks to figure it out.

Comment: Generally just stoping/starting instance will put it on the new hardware. So you can also do this if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS provides guides on what to do when an instance is about to be retired:

- [What do I need to know when my Amazon EC2 instance is scheduled for retirement?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-instance-retirement/)

The easiest way would be to stop/start the instance:

> You are required to stop and then start the instance at your preferred time before the instance retirement date. Stopping and starting the instance moves the instance to another healthy host.

However, exact details depend on your instance type (e.g. EBS based or instance store based), thus please read the guide in the link provided to understand your options which are mostly determined on your actual EC2 instance setup.